# Proving a quadratic sequence is within a neighborhood

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

I'm working on an old text (Buchanan's [Limits: A Transition to Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0395340454)) and I'm having a bit of trouble Proving that a certain sequence is within the general radius E of 2 (that is, that all the terms of the sequence lie in the interval (2 - E,2 + E), where E is a positive real number). Here's my work:

$$2-E<\sqrt{\frac{4n+1}{n}}<2+E$$
$$(2-E)^{2}<4+\frac{1}{n}<(2+E)^{2}$$
$$-4E+E^{2}<\frac{1}{n}<4E+E^{2}$$

And this is where I basically left it. I know $\frac{1}{n}$ cannot get larger than 1 if n is a natural number and I know that the right side of the inequality is always positive but I've always had a bit of trouble with quadratic inequalities. Ideally I'd be able to find a number M such that all n > M are in the interval.

Comment: I have reworked it and I think I have it right, although I used a step whose justification I'm not sure about:

$$(2-E)^{2}<4+\frac{1}{n}<(2+E)^{2}$$

Comment: Forgive the double comment. I have fat fingers.

I have reworked it and I think I have it right, although I used a step whose justification I'm not sure about:

$$2-E< \sqrt{4+\frac{1}{n}}<2+E$$
$$\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{n}}>2$$
True for all n
$$2-E<2$$
True for all E
$$2-E< \sqrt{4+\frac{1}{n}}$$
True for all n. So then the original compound inequality reduces to:
$$4+\frac{1}{n}<(2+E)^{2}$$
$$4+\frac{1}{n}<4+4E+E^{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{n}<4E+E^{2}$$
$$n>\frac{1}{4E+E^{2}}$$

I am unsure as to the validity of the use of the transitive property above.